# Visualization of Rindler coordinization of Minkowski spacetime (Motion in inertial frame wrt. accelerating observer)

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, acceleration, visualization

In Special Relativity, the diagram we most commonly see is the Minkowski coordinization of Rindler Spacetime (the accelerating observer's coordinates as seen in the inertial frame).

Are there any visualizations of the inverse/ how motion in an inertial frame would appear to an accelerating observer?

Comment: do you mean taking into account the lag of the light reaching the observer's eyes?

Comment: @LPZ No; we can define and visualize the accelerating observer's coordinates in the frame of an inertial frame, so I was looking for the inverse.

Answer (score 0):

These are screengrabs taken from this [wonderful set of lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJHszsWbB6hqlw73QjgZcFh4DrkQLSCQa) on SR and GR (Relativity 105f to be precise).
The images are self explanatory.[image]

[image]